# Accessing data that does not pass equality check on perfplot

Tags: python, performance, perfplot

I'm running script that compares performance of two different functions `f1` and `f2`. It can't pass an `equality_check` and raises `AssertionError: Equality check failure. (f1, f2)`. How can I access argument and outputs of functions where it fails?

```
perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: np.random.randint(0, n, size = n),
    kernels=[f1, f2],
    n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(3, 14)],
    logx=True,
    logy=True,
    xlabel="n",
    equality_check=lambda x, y: np.array_equal(x, y)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each step, the argument is passed to the functions `f1` and `f2` by perfplot, and the outputs of both functions are passed to the function specified in the parameter `equality_check` of `perfplot.show` (or `perfplot.bench`) function:

```
equality_check=foo  # foo(x, y)
```

In the code you provided, you defined that parameter with an anonymous function (lambda):

```
equality_check=lambda x, y: np.array_equal(x, y)
```

Check if the two functions are indeed producing the same result (for the same input), and if that result is a NumPy array with the same shape, since you are using `np.array_equal(x, y)`.

---

If you still want to inspect those values during the process (but I recommend you check the functions `f1` and `f2` first), you can define the `equality_check` function as follows:

```
def foo(x, y):
    equal = np.array_equal(x, y)
    if not equal:
        print(x, y)
    return equal
```

That way, the outputs of `f1` and `f2` that cause the exception will be printed.